# Problems connecting ST-Link V2 and STM32F4 discovery board

Tags: stm32f4, st-link, stm32f4-discovery

I'm unable to connect to my [STM32F4Discovery](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) board using an [ST-Link/v2](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html).

I've removed jumpers from CN3, connected the cables correctly but the utility tool won't detect anything...

Using the [ST-Link/v2 manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00026748.pdf):

```
PIN1  (VAPP)      -> VDD
PIN7  (TMS_SWDIO) -> PA13
PIN9  (TCK_SWCLK) -> PA14
PIN20 (GND)       -> GND
```

Here is the physical connection:

[image]

And software settings:

[image]

This is the error message that I get when trying to connect:

[image]

Here is the log message that I get in trace:

```
ST-Link/V2 device detected
Target voltage detected: 0.601975
Driving NRST low
Error getting target IDCODE: if SWD, check SWD connection
Error (4) while initializing ST-Link in SWD mode
```

Please help, it's driving me mad...

Comment: Do you know that the Discovery has an on-board ST-Link?

Comment: Yes, but I soldered another SMT32F chip on an adapter board and tried to access it. I couldn't and then fallen back to a device I know it should work (discovery board) and now having the same issues. So I need to make it work on a professional made board and only then I can move with 100% certainty to my own board.

Comment: I see, then never mind my comment.

Comment: I am getting the same issue :( StjepanV could you clarify how did you fix the problem, please? Thanks,
Mariano

Comment: Hi @MarianoJimenezBrenes! My problem was that I wasn't supplying a dedicated VCC for the chip (3V in my case). You need to power the chip separately. The JTAG VCC pin is just for voltage detection, not for sourcing power.

Comment: Although this post was useful to me, I'd like to add that the picture is wrong. You correctly said that: PIN1 -> VDD PIN7 -> PA13 PIN9 -> PA14 PIN20 -> GND But on the picture you have: PIN1 -> VDD PIN9 -> PA13 PIN11 -> PA14 PIN20 -> GND The problem is with google image search engine, lazy people would make wrong connections (as myself on my first attempt hehe). P.D. This should be a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow me yet ;)

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182763/how-to-use-an-external-st-link-v2-with-the-stm32f4-discovery-board

Comment: -1 for posting a picture which shows incorrect SWD connections differing from the text as the middle two pins are incorrectly connected off-by-1 at pins 9 and 11 of the STLINK instead of pins 7 and 9 where they belong.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Do you know if there is any reason this wouldn't work for the newer [STM32F407G-DISC1 rev](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html)? I have everything wired correctly, but when I try to program with [openocd](http://openocd.org/) I get an error `Error: timed out while waiting for target halted | TARGET: stm32f4x.cpu - Not halted | embedded:startup.tcl:477: Error: ** Unable to reset target **`

Comment: This whole business of using an external STLINK on a board that has one built in is silly to begin with...

Comment: @ChrisStratton It's useful for prototyping when you don't want to include the programmer in the final design. I think this is the problem: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/365146/194001

Comment: No, it's pointless.  If you want to have a programmer, install the jumpers.  If you don't want to have a programmer remove them.  Wiring in an external one is just silly until you get to a custom board or breakout prototype that doesn't have its own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Target voltage detected: 0.601975

You need to power your target. The debug adapter does *not* provide power, it uses the `Vtarget` pin to determine the output voltage levels.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Now that I have connected 3.3V input it starts to blink and all that demo stuff but I have a new error now: ST-Link/V2 device detected
Target voltage detected: 3.242133
Error getting target IDCODE: if SWD, check SWD connection
Error (4) while initializing ST-Link in SWD mode

Comment: "Hardware reset" requires the reset line to be connected. This is apparently not the case.

Comment: I connected it now, and it pulls the NRST pin down and it blinks for a moment when I press the connect button and then just throws an error above. And I've tried using Normal mode but it's giving me the same error.

Comment: So, the problem was when I connected discovery board using USB, even though the CN3 jumpers were not connected it still recognized onboard ST-Link v2 and tried to use that one... After painful realization switching it to a external one it worked just fine! Thanks to everybody involved!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you use the GPIOA port in your source code. If so, first download program to discovery; your code conflicts with swd pins. When you power your board, your source code changes the pa13 and pa14 pins roles. You must connect swd to your board immediately after reset (and do so after power) before loading your code to the CPU.

What should you do? You should erase the flash memory.

First open the STM32 ST-LINK Utility.

1. push and hold discover black button (nrst button),
2. click target -> setting,
3. select "connect under reset” option; at the same time click refresh and  release discovery board black button,
4. repeat until STM32 ST-LINK Utility connect your board,
5. erase flash memory,
6. enjoy!