# External Power STM32F4DISCOVERY

Tags: power-supply, stm32f4, stm32f4-discovery

This question has already been asked on this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236040/external-power-to-stm32f4-discovery-board) but I cannot comment there. I want to run my STM32F4DISCOVERY board from external power supply, but it does not run as it should. As specified in the link, the led LD1 is red-blinking, and my code is not running. I updated the firmware of the board as suggested in the answers:

### [image: Firmware of STM32 board]

Is there something else I should do ? Some hardware modification maybe ? Currently there are jumpers on CN3 and JP1 connectors. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no meaningful details here to make this an answerable question distinct from the duplicate linked within the question itself.  Additionally the question has been abandoned for several months.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't working on the external power, try it with just the JTAG. Depending on your cable the JTAG could be supplying its power along with your supply which could have unintended results.

Measure the Vcc voltage and make sure its set to what you intended (probably should be 3.3V)

This [blog post](http://survivalengineer.blogspot.com/2013/01/turning-stm32-evaluation-board-into.html) describes how to program and set the jumpers.