# How to use JTAG to connect external ST-LINK/V2 with STM32F407VG discovery board?

Tags: stm32f4, jtag, st-link

I want to isolate the on-board stlink, and use an external ST-Link/v2 to program/flash the board. I have a 20-pin JTAG connector. This is just a temporary, proof-of-concept project.

I have removed the jumpers from CN3 pins as instructed here:

[How to Use an External ST-Link/V2 with the STM32F4 Discovery Board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182763/how-to-use-an-external-st-link-v2-with-the-stm32f4-discovery-board/182765)

I cannot comment on that post because I do not have enough rep points.

I connected:

(JTAG) SWDIO -> PA13

(JTAG) SWCLK -> PA14

(JTAG) GND -> GND

(JTAG) VAPP -> 3V/VDD, as instructed

Also, the post says not to connect the USB. I am not sure which USB this is referring to. An external ST-Link/v2 needs to be powered by an USB, and so does the board. I have tried this: 1)connect only the ST-Link/v2 usb, but this is not enough to power the board. 2)connect only the board usb, but this does not power ST-Link/v2.

I am a beginner and I am using the Linux terminal. I have successfully flashed an example "blinky" program to the board.
I would be very grateful if someone could assist me. Thank you.

Comment: This has been covered here before at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182763/how-to-use-an-external-st-link-v2-with-the-stm32f4-discovery-board - it's important to note that what is supported is SWD, a reduced pin-count alternative, rather than full JTAG.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Sir, I acknowledge the same question was asked before, but my issue was not addressed in that post. I am a complete beginner with stm32 and linux, so please excuse my ignorance. I used only 4 pins from the JTAG as instructed in that post, but I am not sure how to power the board and the external st-link/v2 (that post states: "do not connect usb cable"). I connected the stlink/v2 on my linux computer but that does not power the stm32 board (as expected).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. I was also searching for the same answer. I have a stlink v2 usb but the board i bought from aliexpress based on stm32f103 is having JTAG 20 pin connector